# How to remove the same chunk of text from different texts in a character vector?

Tags: r

I have a character vector that has 231 documents (231 rows by one column). The beginning of each document has a chunk of text that I would like to remove from each of 231 documents.

Let's take an example where each text has the following beginning: *Text that I wish to remove*.:

I tried the following options without results:

```
x <- c("Text that I wish to remove. I really want to remove the text but I cannot do it. I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out.", "Text that I wish to remove. I really want to remove the text but I cannot do it. I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out.", "Text that I wish to remove. I really want to remove the text but I cannot do it. I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out.", "Text that I wish to remove. I really want to remove the text but I cannot do it. I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out.")
strings <- substr(x, 1, 26)

remove_1 <- x %>% str_replace_all(strings)

remove_2 <- gsub(strings, "", x)
ecb_remove <- str_remove_all(ecb_ready, ecb_strings)
```

Ideally, I would like to get:

```
[1] "I really want to remove the text but I cannot do it. I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out."
[2] "I really want to remove the text but I cannot do it. I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out."
[3] "I really want to remove the text but I cannot do it. I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out."
[4] "I really want to remove the text but I cannot do it. I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out."
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try: `substring(x, 29)` or `sub("^Text that I wish to remove. ", "", x)`

Comment: What are `ecb_ready ` and `ecb_strings`?

Comment: @yifyan, sorry I edited. Now it should be clear

Comment: @GKi clever thing to do mate! Thanks a lot

Comment: You should really pay attention to error messages and include them in your question. Like, when you run `str_replace_all` with only two arguments, it gives you an error and say you need to specify the `replacement` argument. So you could try again with `replacement = ""` since you want to replace the match with nothing. (Or just use `str_remove`, as you also try...)

Comment: @GKi any suggestion if the text is instead: `x <- c("Text that I wish to remove. I really want to remove the text but I cannot do it. I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out.", "Text that I wish to remove. I really want to remove the text but I cannot do it. I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out.", "Text that I wish to remove. I really want to remove the text but I cannot do it. I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out.", "Text that I wish to remove. I really want to remove the text but I cannot do it. I hope that stackoverflow will sort it out.")` and I aim to get the same result?

Comment: @Arma_91 Is there a difference to the text you give in the comment, to the text in your question?

Comment: @GKi Main difference is that the lenght of the text to be removed varies, it is not constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the string you want to remove has a fixed length you can use:

```
substring(x, 29)
```

or if it has a fixed pattern you can use:

```
sub("^Text that I wish to remove. ", "", x)
```

In case you want to remove everything until the first `.` you can use:

```
sub("^.*?\\. ", "", x)
```